# How to upload images and file to a server in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, file-upload, httprequest

I use a web service for image processing , it works well in Postman:

[image: postman screenshot]

Now I want to make http request in flutter with Dart:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

static ocr(File image) async {
    var url = '${API_URL}ocr';
    var bytes = image.readAsBytesSync();

    var response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers:{ "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data" } ,
        body: { "lang":"fas" , "image":bytes},
        encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8")
    );

    return response.body;

  }
```

but I don't know how to upload the image file, in above code I get exception: `Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "multipart/form-data".`
How should I write the body of request?

Comment: for a workaround: I ask my server guys to change server api to accept base64 encoded image instead. so I put the `base64` encoded image as a string in body with content type of header equal to  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and it works.

Comment: Similar question answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841729/how-to-upload-image-in-flutter/51322060#51322060

Comment: @AravindVemula I don't want to send base64 encoded bytes

Comment: this answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/49645074/6133481

Comment: Have you tried with content-type "application/octet-stream". I always avoid "multipart/form-data" wherever I can. The best designed file-upload APIs accept  "application/octet-stream" in the POST body, and any parameters are in the URI.

Comment: Here is my[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74255358/2462531) which handled for all the media types based on filePath

Answer (score 81):

Your workaround should work; many servers will accept application/x-www-form-urlencoded as an alternative (although data is encoded moderately inefficiently).

However, it is possible to use dart:http to do this. Instead of using `http.post`, you'll want to use a `http.MultipartFile` object.

From the [dart documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html):

```
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", url);
request.fields['user'] = 'someone@somewhere.com';
request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
    'package',
    'build/package.tar.gz',
    contentType: new MediaType('application', 'x-tar'),
));
request.send().then((response) {
  if (response.statusCode == 200) print("Uploaded!");
});
```

Comment: The docs are wrong per [this github issues](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/140)

Comment: Thanks @Kiana, I didn't notice that. It's fixed now. Although the `master` of dart.http is much different than the currently released 0.11.3+16, so I would expect this to eventually become incorrect.

Comment: Thx bro your code helped me to solve sending fields (string) in MultipartFile in Flutter

Comment: @rmtmckenzie what is the 'package' and 'build/package.tar.gz' parameters in MultipartFile.fromPath

Comment: Package is the name of the field (if it was a form on the web it'd be the name of the input), and build/package.tar.gz is the path. That example was really more specific to a server though; you could use one of MultipartFile's other constructors like .fromBytes or the one that uses a stream instead.

Comment: Hi, if I want to upload video, I can use this method also?

Comment: @dipgirl As long as your server accepts and knows what the data you're sending it (and you should set the MediaType to the right thing), you can send anything. The example in the code isn't even sending an image but rather a tar file

Comment: How can I convert back to image

Comment: Here is my[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74255358/2462531) which handled for all the media types based on filePath

Answer (score 66):

I'd like to recommend [dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio) package to you , [dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio) is a powerful Http client for Dart/Flutter, which supports Interceptors, FormData, Request Cancellation, File Downloading, Timeout etc.

[dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio) is very easy to use, in this case you can:

**Sending FormData:**

```
FormData formData = new FormData.from({
   "name": "wendux",
   "file1": new UploadFileInfo(new File("./upload.jpg"), "upload1.jpg")
});
response = await dio.post("/info", data: formData)
```

More details please refer to [dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio)。

Comment: Please write here the solution instead of including a link that could be broken in the future. Thanks!

Comment: can to change image file name using DIO?

Comment: @wendu Can I know where UploadFileInfo() function come from?

Comment: @dipgirl The UploadFileInfo is deprecated, right now there is MultiPartFromFile class for to do this. Here is a sample https://github.com/flutterchina/dio#sending-formdata

Comment: it hard to decide on this, since while some people say Dio promisses a lot, other say it also fails a lot and witout providing meaningfull error messages...

Answer (score 58):

This can be achieved using the MultipartRequest class (https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html)

Change the media type and uri as needed.

```
uploadFile() async {
    var postUri = Uri.parse("<APIUrl>");
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
    request.fields['user'] = 'blah';
    request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', await File.fromUri("<path/to/file>").readAsBytes(), contentType: new MediaType('image', 'jpeg')))

    request.send().then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) print("Uploaded!");
    });
  }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. :) tnq so much :) just to add:- please add " import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart'; " for contentType

Comment: works for me, just changed ```File.fromUri("<path/to/File">) ``` to ```File.fromUri(Uri.parse("<path/to/file>"))```

Comment: Why the response doesn't have response.body

Comment: @BagusAjiSantoso request.send doesn't return ```Future<Response>```, It returns ```Future<StreamedResponse>```. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520829/how-to-get-response-body-with-request-send-in-dart/55521892

Comment: Where are you important "MediaType" from?

Comment: I'm struggling to put my image file path. Image I'm getting form imagePicker `File.fromUri("<path/to/file>"` [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69204607/how-to-pass-image-file-to-the-body-of-http-request-post-in-flutter ]

Comment: @OliverDixon import package http_parser

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not just using ```http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
    'file', filePath); ``` and going through ```fromBytes(readAsBytes())```? Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

I found a working example without using any external plugin , this only uses

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
```

Code

```
var stream =
        new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
    // get file length
    var length = await imageFile.length(); //imageFile is your image file
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
    }; // ignore this headers if there is no authentication

    // string to uri
    var uri = Uri.parse(Constants.BASE_URL + "api endpoint here");

    // create multipart request
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

  // multipart that takes file
    var multipartFileSign = new http.MultipartFile('profile_pic', stream, length,
        filename: basename(imageFile.path));

    // add file to multipart
    request.files.add(multipartFileSign);

    //add headers
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    //adding params
    request.fields['loginId'] = '12';
    request.fields['firstName'] = 'abc';
   // request.fields['lastName'] = 'efg';

    // send
    var response = await request.send();

    print(response.statusCode);

    // listen for response
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);

    });
```

Comment: what do you mean by `basename`

Comment: import this package   import 'package:path/path.dart';

Comment: hmm you know that path, async and http are extenal plugins, right?

Comment: Amazing work brother.
The problem which didn't solve in 3 days you solved it in 30 minutes.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you @Laraib.Sheikh

Comment: it works, I appreciate you providing a response message.

Answer (score 18):

How to upload image file using restAPI in flutter/dart.

This work for me.

```
var postUri = Uri.parse("apiUrl");

http.MultipartRequest request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);

http.MultipartFile multipartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
    'file', filePath); 

request.files.add(multipartFile);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();


print(response.statusCode);
```

Answer (score 11):

Updated 2021 way:

using flutter [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http)  and [mime](https://pub.dev/packages/mime)

```
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
import 'dart:io';


  Future<dynamic> multipartImageUpload(String baseUrl, String api, File image) async {
    var uri = Uri.parse(baseUrl + api);
    final mimeTypeData =
        lookupMimeType(image.path, headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8]).split('/');

    // Intilize the multipart request
    final imageUploadRequest = http.MultipartRequest('PUT', uri);

    // Attach the file in the request
    final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', image.path,
        contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]));
    imageUploadRequest.files.add(file);

    // add headers if needed
    //imageUploadRequest.headers.addAll(<some-headers>);

    try {
      final streamedResponse = await imageUploadRequest.send();
      final response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: how to PUT data?

Comment: What did you mean by PUT data? if you mean data by just a field then  imageUploadRequest.fields['fieldName'] = 'your value';

Answer (score 10):

Use [MultipartRequest](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html) class.
**How to upload image file using restAPI in flutter/dart**

```
  void uploadImage1(File _image) async {

    // open a byteStream
    var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(_image.openRead()));
    // get file length
    var length = await _image.length();

    // string to uri
    var uri = Uri.parse("enter here upload URL");

    // create multipart request
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    // if you need more parameters to parse, add those like this. i added "user_id". here this "user_id" is a key of the API request
    request.fields["user_id"] = "text";

    // multipart that takes file.. here this "image_file" is a key of the API request
    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('image_file', stream, length, filename: basename(_image.path));

    // add file to multipart
    request.files.add(multipartFile);

    // send request to upload image
    await request.send().then((response) async {
      // listen for response
      response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
        print(value);
      });

    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

name spaces:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Answer (score 8):

**UPLOAD IMAGE TO SERVER WITH FORM DATA**

To upload image to server you need a [dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio) library.

**Features:**

1. Authorization (adding token)
2. Adding extra field like: username, etc
3. Adding Image to upload

**Code example:**

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart' as dio;
import 'dart:convert';

    try {
      ///[1] CREATING INSTANCE
      var dioRequest = dio.Dio();
      dioRequest.options.baseUrl = '<YOUR-URL>';

      //[2] ADDING TOKEN
      dioRequest.options.headers = {
        'Authorization': '<IF-YOU-NEED-ADD-TOKEN-HERE>',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      };

      //[3] ADDING EXTRA INFO
      var formData =
          new dio.FormData.fromMap({'<SOME-EXTRA-FIELD>': 'username-forexample'});

      //[4] ADD IMAGE TO UPLOAD
      var file = await dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(image.path,
            filename: basename(image.path),
            contentType: MediaType("image", basename(image.path)));

      formData.files.add(MapEntry('photo', file));

      //[5] SEND TO SERVER
      var response = await dioRequest.post(
        url,
        data: formData,
      );
      final result = json.decode(response.toString())['result'];
    } catch (err) {
      print('ERROR  $err');
    }
```

Comment: I get error at "MediaType". Am I missing any imports?

Comment: import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
this should solve your issue.

Answer (score 8):

To add a header and use http multipart with https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker Plugin,

**This is the code.**

```
var request =  http.MultipartRequest(
        'POST', Uri.parse(myurl)

      );
      //Header....
      request.headers['Authorization'] ='bearer $authorizationToken';
      
       request.fields['PropertyName'] = propertyName;
    request.fields['Country'] = country.toString();
    request.fields['Description'] = des;
    request.fields['State'] = state.toString();
       request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      'ImagePaths',
      learnImage,
      filename: 'some-file-name.jpg',
  contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg"),
    )
        );
var response = await request.send();
print(response.stream);
print(response.statusCode);
final res = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
  print(res.body);
```

To use HTTP and https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker  PLUGIN

This is the code

```
var request =  http.MultipartRequest(
        'POST', Uri.parse(myurl)

      );
      request.headers['Authorization'] ='bearer $authorizationToken';
       request.fields['PropertyName'] = propertyName;
    request.fields['Country'] = country.toString();
    request.fields['Description'] = des;
    request.fields['State'] = state.toString();
       request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'ImagePaths',
      file.path
    )
        );
var response = await request.send();
    print(response.stream);
    print(response.statusCode);
    final res = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
      print(res.body);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Working Code**

```
String path = userSelectedImagePath;
    Map<String, String> data = {
      "name": firstName!,
      "email": userEmail!
    };
   

    String token = await LocaldbHelper().getToken();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };


   var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'POST',
        Uri.parse(ApiUrl.updateProfile),
      );
      request.fields.addAll(data);
      request.headers.addAll(headers);
      var multipartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
          'avatar', path); //returns a Future<MultipartFile>
      request.files.add(multipartFile);
      http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
      final respStr = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      var jsonData = jsonDecode(respStr);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // success
      } else {
        // error
      }
```

Comment: Improve your answer with supporting information, like explaining the code for better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

With Hearder
upload image

```
Future uploadImageMedia(File fileImage, String token) async {


  final mimeTypeData =
        lookupMimeType(fileImage.path, headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8]).split('/');
         final imageUploadRequest =
        http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(mainUrlSite + "wp-json/wp/v2/media"));

    final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', fileImage.path,
        contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]));

    imageUploadRequest.files.add(file);
    imageUploadRequest.headers.addAll({
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
    });
    try {
      final streamedResponse = await imageUploadRequest.send();

      streamedResponse.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
        print(value);
        return Future.value(value);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add this method definition lookupMimeType()..

Answer (score 3):

Just leaving this here, if anyone is trying to upload a pdf or any other document using `MultipartRequest` method.

Just add the content type as -
`contentType: new MediaType('application', 'pdf')`

Answer (score 3):

Good code with Dio and FilePicker for post file on your server. I use flutter for the web.

[FilePicker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)
[Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

1. First you need writing Dio post method.

```
    Future postImportClient(PlatformFile file) async {
        try {
          var urlBase = 'your url';
          var mfile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(file.bytes!, filename: file.name);
          var formData = FormData();
          formData.files.add(MapEntry('file', mfile));
          await _dio.post(urlBase, data: formData);
        } on DioError catch (error) {
          throw Exception(error);
        }
      }
```

2. Initial FilePicker and get file.

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePickerWeb.platform.pickFiles();
if (result != null) {
var file = result.files.single;
await client.postImportClient(file);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I use **Dio** library with **put** method:

```
    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'simpleParam': 'example',
      'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath, filename: 'file.jpg')
    });

    var dio = Dio();
    dio.options.headers[HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader] = myToken;

    var response = new Response(); //Response from Dio
    response = await dio.put(myUrl + "/myApi", data: formData);
```

The result is in response.data

Answer (score 2):

create FormData:

```
final formDataMap = <String, dynamic>{};
formDataMap["stringKey"] = "string";
List<MultipartFile> multipartImageList = [];
await Future.forEach(imagePaths as List<String>,(String path) async {
  final multiPartFile = await MultipartFile.fromFile(
                          path,
                          contentType: MediaType("image", "jpeg"),
                        );
  multipartImageList.add(multiPartFile);
});
formDataMap["image[]"] = multipartImageList;
final formData = FormData.fromMap(formDataMap);
```

With Retrofit & Dio:

```
@MultiPart()
@POST("{{url}}")
Future<dynamic> uploadFormData(
  @Body() FormData formData,
);
```

Comment: how about pdf file?

Comment: @H.Fa8 You need to change the media type that is compatible with the file you want to upload

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
  result[HttpKeys.status] = false;
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
  request.fields.addAll(body);

  if (avatar.path.isNotEmpty) {
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('uploadedImg', avatar.path));
  }

  request.headers.addAll(headers);

  http.StreamedResponse streamResponse = await request.send();

  final response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamResponse);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var resMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
    debugPrint('<==    ==>');
    // debugPrint(response.body);
    result[HttpKeys.status] = true;
    result[HttpKeys.message] = resMap[HttpKeys.message];
    result[HttpKeys.data] = resMap['data'];

    return result;
  } else {
    var resMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
    result[HttpKeys.message] = resMap[HttpKeys.message];
    return result;
  }
} catch (error) {
  result[HttpKeys.message] = error.toString();
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Map<String, dynamic> result = {
      HttpKeys.status: false,
      HttpKeys.message: ':-(',
      HttpKeys.data: null,
      HttpKeys.token: '',
    };

Future<Map<String, dynamic>>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

I write a example using flutter to upload file with `multipart/form-data` format with 2 steps. Both steps contains optional package for options. The example request contains 2 fields: **File** for {file:slide.pdf} and **Text** for {owner:Gary}.

- Pick file: [html](https://pub.dev/packages/html), [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html), or [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)
- Upload: [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) or [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

[image]

### Stpe 1: Pick File (to bytes data)

**Method 1**: Use [html](https://pub.dev/packages/html)(built-in library, web only), or [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html)

example code:

```
// choose one of below pacakges
import 'dart:html' as html;
// import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

Future<html.File?> pickHtmlFile() async {
  final uploadElement = html.FileUploadInputElement()
    ..multiple = false
    ..click();
  await uploadElement.onChange.first;
  return uploadElement.files?.first;
}

Future<Uint8List?> readBytes(html.File file) async {
  final reader = html.FileReader()
    ..readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  await reader.onLoadEnd.first;
  return reader.result as Uint8List?;
}


...

final htmlFile = await pickHtmlFile();
if (htmlFile == null) return;
final bytes = await readBytes(htmlFile);
if (bytes == null) return;
// htmlFile.name => file name
// bytes => byte data of the file 

...
```

**Method 2**: use [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) (Recommand)

example code:

```
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

final picked = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
final platformFile = picked?.files.single;
final bytes = platformFile?.bytes;
if (platformFile == null || bytes == null) return;
// platformFile.name => file name
// bytes => byte data of the file
```

### Step2: Upload Formdata with POST

**Method1**: use [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) (Official)

example code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

...

final multipartFile =
    http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', bytes, filename: filename);
final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST',Uri.parse('[YOUR API URL HERE]'))
  ..files.add(multipartFile)
  ..fields['owner'] = 'Gary';

final responseStream = await request.send();
final response = await http.Response.fromStream(responseStream);
// response.statusCode => 200 is OK
// response.body => response data here
```

**Method2**: use [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

example code:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart' as dio;

...

final multipartFile = dio.MultipartFile.fromBytes(bytes, filename: filename);
final formData = dio.FormData.fromMap({'file': multipartFile, 'owner': 'Gary'});
final response = await dio.Dio().post('[YOUR API URL HERE]',data: formData,);
// response.statusCode => 200 is OK
// response.data => response data here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Future postData ()async{
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('url'));
      request.fields.addAll({
        'docType': 'Passport',
        'docCountry': 'Italy'
      });
      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('documentFront', '${imagepath}'));
      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('documentBack', '${imagePath}'));

      var streamedResponse = await request.send();
      var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return jsonDecode(response.body);
      }
      else {
        return jsonDecode(response.body);
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code where I am passing **Image**, route which may be like **'/register',** and data which is **Map<String, String>** like `data={'directory':'profile'}`.

**For Uploading Image to Laravel API, Authorization in header is compulsory otherwise it would return "You don't have permission to access this resource". I am passing token as EMPTY string like `String token=''` as I am uploading
Image at user registration time**

This **Authorization for read and write** is defined in domainurl/public/.htaccess file, you can change it

Try to understand the below code and all the issue would be resolve.

```
  Future uploadImage({
    required XFile file,
    required String route,
    required Map<String, String> data,
  }) async {
    String url = API_Url + route;
    final uri = Uri.parse(url);
    try {
      http.MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
      http.MultipartFile multipartFile =
          await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', file.path);
      request.files.add(multipartFile);
      request.headers.addAll(_header());
      request.fields.addAll(data);
      var streamedResponse = await request.send();
      var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
      print(jsonDecode(response.body));
      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  _header() {
    return {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}',
    };
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

With dio I do like this:

```
Future<void> _uploadFileAsFormData(String path) async {
  try {
    final dio = Dio();

    dio.options.headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };

    final file =
      await MultipartFile.fromFile(path, filename: 'test_file');

    final formData = FormData.fromMap({'file': file}); // 'file' - this is an api key, can be different

    final response = await dio.put( // or dio.post
      uploadFileUrlAsString,
      data: formData,
    );
  } catch (err) {
    print('uploading error: $err');
  }
}
```