# How to get response body with request.send() in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm doing an api request uploading an image with

```
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
var response = await request.send()
```

in dart using flutter. I can then check the response code with for instance

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   print('ok');
}
```

with other calls I can also get the response body with

```
var result = response.body;
```

however when using request.send() I can't seem to find out how to get the response body result.

Any help or input is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I checked the docs for [request.send](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/http/latest/http/BaseRequest/send.html) I returns `Future<StreamedResponse>` instead of `Future<Response>`

Digging more for [StreamedResponse](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/http/latest/http/StreamedResponse-class.html) I found that it `response.stream` which is a [ByteStream](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/http/latest/http/ByteStream-class.html)

Here is what you can do to get response in String

```dart
final response = await request.send();
final respStr = await response.stream.bytesToString();
```

In my opinoin you should only use request.send if you want streamed response instead of "collected" response. More about [streams in dart here](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/streams)

Comment: The official documentation expects you to use send for behaviour composition (retrying requests, setting user agent, etc). This is probably why most people end up with having to decapsulate their response from the StreamedResponse...

Comment: so if I don't want a streamed response, but I want to send a Multipart Request, how should I do it?

Answer (score 105):

Just use `http.Response.fromStream()`

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var streamedResponse = await request.send()
var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
```

Comment: hi, using this approach  print(resBody);
    bank_name = resBody['data']['BankName'];             but getting error Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (13761): Receiver: null
E/flutter (13761): Tried calling: []("BankName")

Answer (score 10):

So this is my expected json object:

```
 {"hasErrors":true,"errorMessage":"Some Error Message","done":false}
```

On the basis of 'hasErrors' property I want to perform some action.

This is how I get it from Http Post Request:

```
  var request = http.Request('POST', url);
  request.body = json.encode(data);
  request.headers.addAll(headers);

  var streamedResponse = await request.send();
  var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
  final result = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  return !result['hasErrors'];
```

Comment: Saved my time. This I am using with Laravel json error response with a streamed request.

Answer (score 7):

You can cast after first response, look :

```
var postUri = Uri.parse("http://my-api.com/updatePhoto");
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);

request.fields['user_id'] = user_id

request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
  'photo',
  myPhoto.absolute.path,
  contentType: new MediaType('application', 'x-tar'),
));

request.send().then((result) async {

  http.Response.fromStream(result)
      .then((response) {

    if (response.statusCode == 200)
    {
      print("Uploaded! ");
      print('response.body '+response.body);
    }

    return response.body;

  });
}).catchError((err) => print('error : '+err.toString()))
    .whenComplete(()
{});
```

Answer (score 5):

> this work for me  in below example i decode the stream responsed to my
> model class(UserModel)

```
 var streamedResponse = await request.send();
        var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var parsed = jsonDecode(response.body);
          UserModel userModel= UserModel.fromJson(parsed);
          return userModel;
}
else{
print(error);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `MultipartRequest` returns a `Streamed Response` since you used `request.send`. You will need to extract the string value from the response like below:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart'

var request = new MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
var response = await request.send()

// Extract String from Streamed Response
var responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
```

In this case the `responseString` will be just like `response.body` of

```
final response = await post(URL, body : map);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    import 'package:http/http.dart'
    import 'dart:convert';
    
    var request = new MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
    var response = await request.send()
    
    // Extract String from Streamed Response
    var responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
    final decodedMap = json.decode(responseString);
    print(decodedMap['id']);
    print(decodedMap['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was,

```
await res.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(json.decoder).first;
```