# How to get response from streamed response in flutter?

Tags: api, http, flutter, dart

I am developing an app using flutter and I am using http library to call the api I built.

and I want to make a multipart request to send files and it sends it as well but I can't receive any response from the server because the object returned is StreamResponse.

please tell me how to get the body of the response.

Code Snippet:

```dart
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('$SERVER_URL/signup'));
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'image',
      user.image,
      filename: 'image',
      contentType: MediaType('multipart/form-data', 'multipart/form-data'),
    ));



    StreamResponse x = await request.send();
    //get body of the response
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get response body with request.send() in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520829/how-to-get-response-body-with-request-send-in-dart)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use http.Response.fromStream()

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var streamedResponse = await request.send();
var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
```

Comment: Getting error Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.

Comment: To avoid this error, you should make sure that you only listen to the StreamedResponse object once.

Answer (score 4):

`StreamedResponse` has a `stream` getter as you'd expect that delivers a stream of byte arrays.

Assuming that you want characters instead of bytes, push those through the appropriate character decoder - let's assume UTF-8.

You then might want all those joined into a single string, so we can use `join`. Giving you:

```
  print(await x.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).join());
```