# Flutter: download large file by chunks

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-http

I need to get a large file/binary data from the server (I'm using http package). I want to download it in chunks, since it's so big, and write all the chunks into one file. How can I do that?

Comment: you don't need it, instead use streamed http response so you can download any file you want, more here: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/StreamedResponse/stream.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60875421/how-to-get-response-from-streamed-response-in-flutter