# How to convert List<Asset> to List<File> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker) to get mutliple images from gallery and it return a list of Asset, now I want to send it to server, I am use FormDate but there image path required.

1. Is there any other way to send **Asset** image to server?
2. how to convert `List<Asset>` to `List<File>`.
3. how to get image path from **Asset**

Or any other method to done this task(Choose mutliple images from storage and send them to server).

```
List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();

FormData imageFormData = FormData.fromMap({
  "files": images.map((image) async {
     return await MultipartFile.fromFile('assets/${image.name}', filename: image.name);
     }).toList(),
});
```

Comment: use [MultipartRequest](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html)

Comment: @Naeem if you find out the answer, please post it below, I also using same multi-image picker library, can you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
List<MultipartFile> multipart = List<MultipartFile>();
for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var path = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(images[i].identifier);
  multipart.add(await MultipartFile.fromFile(path, filename: 'myfile.jpg'));
}
FormData imageFormData = FormData.fromMap({"files": multipart,});
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of flutter_absolute_path  package.

add flutter_absolute_path: ^1.0.6 in pubsec.yaml

This will convert file path from this format : “content://media/external/images/media/5275”
To this format (absolute format)
"/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_00124.jpg”

Then make use of this method:

Future<List> imagePicker() async{

```
List<Asset> assetArray = [];
List <File> fileImageArray = [];

try {
    assetArray = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 300,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets:  assetArray ,
        cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
            actionBarColor: "",
            actionBarTitle: "ImagePicker",
            allViewTitle: "All Photos",
            useDetailsView: false,
            selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
            ),
        );
}on Exception catch (e) {
    print( e.toString());
}

assetArray.forEach((imageAsset) async {
    final filePath = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(imageAsset.identifier);
    
    File tempFile = File(filePath);
    if (tempFile.existsSync()) {
        fileImageArray.add(tempFile);
    }
});

return fileImageArray;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think you can read assets file as file before sending over as below:

```
File imageFile = File('yourAssetsUriPath.jpg');
```

- yourAssetsUriPath is pointing to your assets folder by default, so you can simply put your filename in the path.

As for http post it, you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51813960/2281066)