# How to pass image file to the body of Http request (POST) in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I Took a variable in my State **`File? image;`**

**Then Accesing image from my device**

```
  void filePicker() async {
    final File? selectedImage =await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    print(selectedImage!.path);
    setState(() {
      image = selectedImage;
    });
  }
```

Then tyring to pass the **`image file`** along with other http body parameters. If I didn't pass the image file, then the API didn't show any error. But I need to pass the image file to get the correct result.
As I Explicitly throw Exception, so its throwing exception like **`Faild to fetch`** and message in `ScaffoldMessenger` --> `Somthing went wrong`

```
 Future<void> SaveCustomTestBooking() async {
var jsonResponse;
if (EncUserId.isNotEmpty) {
  var postUri = Uri.parse("http://medbo.digitalicon.in/api/medboapi/SaveCustomTestBooking");
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', postUri);
  request.fields['VisitDate'] = _selectedDate;
  request.fields['EncUserId'] = EncUserId;
  request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('image',await File.fromUri(Uri.parse(image!.path)).readAsBytes(),contentType: new MediaType('image', 'jpeg')));

  request.send().then((response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Uploaded!");
      Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DieticianAfterDateSelectPage(rresponse:DieticianEncBookingIdModel.fromJson(jsonResponse),)));
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Somthing went wrong")));
      throw Exception("Faild to fetch");
    }
  });
}
```

}

Comment: did you print out `base64Encode(image!.readAsBytesSync())` to see if already contains `'data:image/jpg;base64,'`

Comment: No . But Instead  Im displaying the image in my device. and its showing the image

Comment: I also try `'UserFile':image.toString(),` same error... Its necessary to convert the image to `base64` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `MultiPart` post method. Take a look at [this](https://dev.to/carminezacc/advanced-flutter-networking-part-1-uploading-a-file-to-a-rest-api-from-flutter-using-a-multi-part-form-data-post-request-2ekm).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass image file simply in this way:

```
   //header
   var headers = {
          'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        };
   
   //setup request
    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
            "POST", Uri.parse("your api url"));
    
    //add files to reqest body
     request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
          'your feild name',
          pickedFile.path,
        ));
   
    //add header
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    //send request and return response
        try {
          var streamedResponse = await request.send();
          var response = http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
          return response;
        } catch (e) {
          rethrow;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to slove it using `Multipart`.. Here is full API function code of mine

```
     Future<void> SaveCustomTestBooking() async {
var jsonResponse;
if (EncUserId.isNotEmpty) {
  var response = http.MultipartRequest('POST',Uri.parse("http://myApiTestBooking"));

  response.fields['VisitDate'] = _selectedDate;
  response.fields['EncUserId'] = EncUserId;
  response.fields['Description'] = testTextController.text;

  response.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    "UserFile", File(image!.path).readAsBytesSync(),//UserFile is my JSON key,use your own and "image" is the pic im getting from my gallary 
    filename:"Image.jpg",
    contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg')));



  response.send().then((response) async {
  if (response.statusCode == 200){
    isApiCallProcess = false;
    final respBody = await response.stream.bytesToString();// this is how we print body for Multipart request
     jsonResponse = json.decode(respBody.toString());
    print(respBody);
    print("Uploaded!");

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Booked"),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF00b3a4),
          ));

       //  Navigator.push(context,new MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) =>new MyTestReqDetailsPage(),));
         Navigator.push(context,new MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) =>new Home2(),));

  } 
});


}
}
```