# req.file and req.files are undefined when calling the endpoint from mobile app's (Flutter) frontend, but from postman it's working fine

Tags: node.js, flutter, express, multer, multipart

I'm using `multer` in the backend:

```
const filefilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/webp') {
        cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cb(null, false)
    }
}

var upload = multer({ dest: 'public/uploads', fileFilter: filefilter, limits: { fieldSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 } });

router.post("/uploadFile",  

(req, res) => {


    upload.single("myFile")(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          // An error occurred when uploading
          console.log('Err: ', err);
          return;
        } else {
           console.log('req.file: ', JSON.stringify(req.file));  
           console.log('req.files: ', JSON.stringify(req.files));
           return;
        }
      });

    res.send({'Success': 'File uploaded'});
  });
```

When the endpoint is getting invoked using POSTMAN, then it's working fine (means the `req.file` is containing the selected file). The output is:

[image: POSTMAN screenshot]

---

The console output of the backend is:

```
req.file:  {"fieldname":"myFile","originalname":"ronaldo.jpeg","encoding":"7bit","mimetype":"image/jpeg","destination":"public/uploads","filename":"44d2b324d2185b2a48d59a4b541b4dc3","path":"public/uploads/44d2b324d2185b2a48d59a4b541b4dc3","size":126154}
req.files:  undefined
```

---

The Flutter (Dart) code sample to invoke the endpoint is:

```
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:3000/uploadFile'));
request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('myFile', filePath));

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

In this case, the console output of the backend is:

```
req.file:  undefined
req.files:  undefined
```

---

**NOTE:**

I have tried explicitly setting the `'Content-Type'`, `'Accept'` and `'Content-Encoding'` as `'multipart/form-data'` in the headers while sending the request. But, that didn't workout too. Even tried using the [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package, no success with that as well.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125191/how-to-upload-images-and-file-to-a-server-in-flutter

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, can you please point out to a particular solution that you're referring to using that post ?

Comment: I guess that you are not sending the file correctly

Comment: As I have mentioned, I have tried using the Dio package and also tried setting up the headers. But none of that worked out.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, when I'm consoling out the `request.files` on the frontend, then it's printing the `[Instance of 'MultipartFile']` in the console. So, it means the file is being sent correctly from the frontend.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, can you please tell me, as per your understanding of the problem that the issue is on frontend side or on backend side ?