# Flutter converting single image upload to multiple image upload

Tags: flutter, file-upload

I am new here and I am trying all I can to explain with respect to the regulation here. I have a flutter image upload for a single image at a time but I am looking for a way around how to convert it into uploading multiple images at a time. Below is what my single image upload looks like:

```
class UploadImageDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  UploadImageDemo() : super();

  final String title = "Upload Image Demo";

  @override
  UploadImageDemoState createState() => UploadImageDemoState();
}

class UploadImageDemoState extends State<UploadImageDemo> {
  //
  static final String uploadEndPoint =
      'http://localhost/flutter_test/upload_image.php';
  Future<File> file;
  String status = '';
  String base64Image;
  File tmpFile;
  String errMessage = 'Error Uploading Image';

  chooseImage() {
    setState(() {
      file = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    });
    setStatus('');
  }

  setStatus(String message) {
    setState(() {
      status = message;
    });
  }

  startUpload() {
    setStatus('Uploading Image...');
    if (null == tmpFile) {
      setStatus(errMessage);
      return;
    }
    String fileName = tmpFile.path.split('/').last;
    upload(fileName);
  }

  upload(String fileName) {
    http.post(uploadEndPoint, body: {
      "image": base64Image,
      "name": fileName,
    }).then((result) {
      setStatus(result.statusCode == 200 ? result.body : errMessage);
    }).catchError((error) {
      setStatus(error);
    });
  }

  Widget showImage() {
    return FutureBuilder<File>(
      future: file,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            null != snapshot.data) {
          tmpFile = snapshot.data;
          base64Image = base64Encode(snapshot.data.readAsBytesSync());
          return Flexible(
            child: Image.file(
              snapshot.data,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          );
        } else if (null != snapshot.error) {
          return const Text(
            'Error Picking Image',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        } else {
          return const Text(
            'No Image Selected',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Upload Image Demo"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            OutlineButton(
              onPressed: chooseImage,
              child: Text('Choose Image'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            showImage(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            OutlineButton(
              onPressed: startUpload,
              child: Text('Upload Image'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            Text(
              status,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.green,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                fontSize: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Based on the above everything works perfect for single upload, onn click of `chooseImage` I can pick the image and `showImage` displays it and `startUpload` uploads it to the server side but I want it to pick multiple images at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick multiple images from the galery with pickMultiImage() instead of pickImage().

```
final List<XFile>? images = await _picker.pickMultiImage();
```

Since your backend accepts the images as base64 strings, you have to run over the list of images, convert each image to a base64 string and then submit it via Post Request.

It would be better to send the images via multipart. But then of course you would have to adjust your backend accordingly

[How to upload images and file to a server in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125191/how-to-upload-images-and-file-to-a-server-in-flutter)