# How to send image file with POST request in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to pass an image file that I have taken from the camera, directly as param with a POST method in Flutter.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841729/how-to-upload-image-in-flutter?

Comment: Duplicate question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161862/how-to-send-an-image-to-an-api-in-dart-flutter

Comment: Could you share what have you tried so far? You can post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MultipartFile` from the `http` library

```
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('YourUrl'));
  request.files.add(
    http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      'YourField',
      File('YourFilename').readAsBytesSync(),
      filename: 'YourFilename'
    )
  );
  var res = await request.send();
```