# Submitting a form with image Flutter - type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: dart, flutter

This is my payload:

```
final Map<String, dynamic> registration = {
        'company_name': _companyName,
        'team_name': _teamName,
        'image': _image
      };
```

`company_name` and `team_name` are string as expected. However, `_image` is defined like below:

```
File _image;
```

So when I do the post request I am getting the below error on terminal:

> type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

I know this is happening because I defined `registration` as `<String, dynamic>`. How to fix this?

Comment: where do you want to send the image?

Comment: To an API endpoint using http.post() (note: I control the API as well)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload image in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841729/how-to-upload-image-in-flutter)