# Sending post request flutter with specific requirements

Tags: dart, flutter, httprequest

I need some suggestion on how to send a `POST` request using the `http` module in Flutter with some parameters.

I need to set the `username` to a string(in the body of the request), and also need to set a property to a FILE in the body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload image in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841729/how-to-upload-image-in-flutter)

Comment: This answer may help -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083702/posting-a-file-and-associated-data-to-a-restful-webservice-preferably-as-json. Specifically the base64 string part of the answer Then just use the dart:convert lib to json.encode the map. If I have understood your question correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do requests on Flutter is to use the [Dio package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio)

if your json payload is,

```
{"username":"johndoe", "image":"base64 image data"}
```

In dio the code looks like

```
import "dart:io";
import "dart:convert";
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

// read image bytes from disk as a list
List<int> imageBytes = File("./image.png").readAsBytesSync();

// convert that list to a string & encode the as base64 files
String imageString = base64Encode(imageBytes);

// Send a post request to server
dio.post("/url-to-post-to", data: {"username":"johndoe", "image":imageString});
```

Comment: when i set a post request to register endpoint, i require to add a file to the params

Comment: you mean uploading a file?

Comment: Yes uploading a file my friend

Comment: Hope in answered your question 