# WSDL file upload in flutter?

Tags: file, http, flutter, upload, httpurlconnection

I am fairly new to flutter.  I am looking for some guidance on how to use flutter’s HHTP library correctly.

My challenge is consuming a WSDL service to upload a picture.  Here are two codes (flutter vs. Java) that perform the same function with the same WSDL.  Java works!

I build my flutter code using this example:  How to upload image in Flutter.  [How to upload image in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841729/how-to-upload-image-in-flutter)

But my flutter code below returns server error 500:  See screen shots below for reference and clarity.

```
Future<bool> sentPhotoTransaction () async {
 // URL includes two parameter plus the image file stream.
 String cIPhotoPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.saleson24.saleson24/files/Pictures/scaled_IMG_20200414_161101.jpg";
 String urlString = "http://pro.test.com/ImgHandler.WCFHost/FileManagerService.svc/UploadFile?MobID=20A47616&Sig=b6e61d4e3ee38";
Io.File imageFile;
 imageFile = new Io.File(cIPhotoPath);
 // ***************** create multipart request for POST *****************
 var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(urlString));
 // ***************** create multipart using filepath, string or bytes *****************
 var picture = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("stream", imageFile.path);
 // ***************** add multipart for the picture to request *****************
 request.files.add(picture);
 try {
   var response = await request.send();
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     print("Success");
     return true;
   } else {
     print("POST request did not worked");
     return false;
   }
 } catch(e) {
   print(e.toString());
   return false;
 }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Here is a Java code example that worked with the same WSDL:

```
    java.net.URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);    //Allow Outputs
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);  //Don't use a cached Copy
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    Bitmap full_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    full_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, IMAGE_QUALITY, stream); // Convert stream.
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    dos.write(byteArray);
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();                 // END POST
```

How do I get the flutter code above using the HTTP library above to work?  Is the HHTP Library the correct library to consume WSDL?

Your guidance is appreciated.
Stay @ home.  Be safe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code expands on Lorenzo answer above.  This code worked for me, hope that helps others.

```
    String photoPath = "";      // Your photo location path.
    Io.File file = new Io.File(photoPath);
    var dio = Dio();
    // ***************** Transfer File *****************
    try {
// Convert file to Bytes WITHOUT compression.
//          List<int> postData = await file.readAsBytes();                      
// Convert file to Bytes WITH compression.
          List<int> postData = await compressImageFileAndReturnList(file);      
      var response = await dio.post(urlString,
          data: Stream.fromIterable(postData.map((e) => [e])),
          options: Options(
              followRedirects: false,
              headers: {
                Headers.contentLengthHeader: postData.length, // set content-length
              }
          )
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("Success");
        return true;
      } else {
        print("POST request did not worked");
        return false;
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Dart, at the moment, you're using a multipart request, in Java you're sending a stream. I suggest to try to send a stream too. Try to do it by using the fantastic [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) library.

There is an example in there for sending it:

```dart
// Binary data
List<int> postData = <int>[...];
await dio.post(
  url,
  data: Stream.fromIterable(postData.map((e) => [e])), //create a Stream<List<int>>
  options: Options(
    headers: {
      Headers.contentLengthHeader: postData.length, // set content-length
    },
  ),
);
```

Let me know if you need something more in the comments. Hope it works.

Comment: I presume the picture data goes into definition of List<int> postData = <int>[...];  How do I achieve this?

Comment: I think something like this: List<int> fileBytes = await file.readAsBytes();

Comment: You're missing the code to compress the image, presumably to a lower resolution.

Comment: The problem is on the request and not on the image.

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, Thank you for the help and quick reply.  In concept your answer above is good.  But like Richard mentioned the code was incomplete.  But I got it to work.  I will post a full code sample shortly.  Do did gave me the idea to research DIO library.  I also got it to work using the http.MultipartRequest library as well.  I am trying to figure which is best and faster the HTTP vs. the DIO library.