# How to develop background sync functionality like google photos in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, image, flutter, fetch

I am developing a photo-sharing app in a flutter. I want to know is there any way to upload the photos, sync the photos with the cloud in the background when the user takes a new photo using the default camera app or other.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a question regarding flutter app, I came across few articles that explains step by step procedure to upload images

[Code snipper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49645074/2070800)

[Uploading images on firebase](https://medium.com/codechai/uploading-image-to-firebase-storage-in-flutter-app-android-ios-31ddd66843fc)

[Github repo](https://github.com/geeksilva97/Medium/tree/master/app_upload)