# How to cancel ongoing file upload sent with http.MultipartRequest() in Flutter?

Tags: http, file-upload, dart, flutter

I'm trying to add cancel functionality to file upload in my Flutter app. I'm currently using `http.MultipartRequest()` from `http package` to upload the file. I've tried wrapping the upload with `CancelableOperation` but it only cancels the internal process within my Flutter app and the file still gets uploaded successfully to my Firebase Storage server.

I read the README.md on http package about using `http.Client()` and closing it after the http request is completed. I'm thinking about using `http.Client()` to upload the file and then closing it with the `http.Client().close()` to cancel the http request.

But, I haven't found the right way to upload file with `http.Client` yet. I browsed about it on Google and stackoverflow but all the posts recommend using `http.MultipartRequest()`. [One of the posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600488/how-can-i-upload-a-pdf-using-darts-httpclient)

So, my questions are: 
1. Is it possible to cancel upload file sent with `http.MultipartRequest()` from http package in Flutter? 
2. Am I in the right track with trying to use `http.Client()` ? Or is there any better way to do this?
3. If using `http.Client()` is the only way, then can you please show me how to upload file with `http.Client()`? since it only has `post()` and no `multipartrequest()`.

Sorry for the long text. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I tried using `http.Client.close()` and it did cancel my post http request. So, what I need now is how to upload file with `http.Client.post()`. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Package `http` uses `HTTPClient` under the hood. It wraps that underlying client in an `IOClient`. Most of `http`'s methods (like `get` and `post`) allow you to pass in your own client, but the `MultipartRequest` doesn't (it creates one for each request).

The easiest solution seems to be to subclass it.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class CloseableMultipartRequest extends http.MultipartRequest {
  http.IOClient client = http.IOClient(HttpClient());

  CloseableMultipartRequest(String method, Uri uri) : super(method, uri);

  void close() => client.close();

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send() async {
    try {
      var response = await client.send(this);
      var stream = onDone(response.stream, client.close);
      return new http.StreamedResponse(
        new http.ByteStream(stream),
        response.statusCode,
        contentLength: response.contentLength,
        request: response.request,
        headers: response.headers,
        isRedirect: response.isRedirect,
        persistentConnection: response.persistentConnection,
        reasonPhrase: response.reasonPhrase,
      );
    } catch (_) {
      client.close();
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Stream<T> onDone<T>(Stream<T> stream, void onDone()) =>
      stream.transform(new StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(handleDone: (sink) {
        sink.close();
        onDone();
      }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Richard Heap, it works like a charm! Thank you for taking your time to give me such detailed answer. I really appreciated it :)

Comment: @Richard This solution works if the http client is recreated with every new instance of CloseableMultipartRequest. However, it wouldn't support a reference to a client instance, in that case, it's not a good idea to close the connection to cancel the request.